# Efficient way to get last value with Flux (InfluxDB)

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influxql

I'm changing from the old Influx query to the new Flux language and I'm wondering how to efficiently get the last value of something without knowing when this last value was. So far I can only get the last value by defining a range start time. See code:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
|> range(start: -<some_value>s)
|> filter(fn: (r) => ...
|> keep(columns:["_time", "_value",])
|> last()
```

But the problem is that I don't know a priori when the last value was. So if I make `<some_value>` large it slows down the query for things that had many values in this time range and when I give it a too small value, it won't find the last value when it was too long ago. So my question is how to find the last value in the most efficient way, similar to `SELECT LAST(value)` in the old syntax.

Thanks for the help!

I can't find an example that doesn't define the range.start parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start` parameter with value `0` to start at the very beginning of "all time".

If you experience query slow down with going too much back in time, I suggest to call `keep()` after `last()`, as `keep()` is not a push down op. Please have a look at performance hints in [Optimizing Flux Performance](https://dganais.medium.com/tl-dr-influxdb-tech-tips-optimizing-flux-performance-in-influxdb-cloud-21de08fc50c9). The list of push down functions and combinations is listed in [Start queries with pushdowns](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/optimize-queries/#start-queries-with-pushdowns)